# Multiple process read same file php

Tags: php

I have a little problem inside my application.
I have many process launched automatically, from the server with crontab, written in php to read file inside a folder.

Sometimes different process read the same file and create a problem inside the application.
Is there a way to manage this problem?
Actually I read all files inside a folder, read each of them and delete immediately, but sometimes another process read the same file before I delete It.

This is my script written with **cakephp3** (so some classes like File is only for cakephp3 but isn't the point of the question) to read and delete:

```
$xml_files = glob(TMP . 'xml/*.xml');
foreach($xml_files as $fileXml)
{
   //read the file and put into a string or array or object
    $explStr = explode('/', $fileXml);
    $filename = $explStr[count($explStr) - 1];
    $path = TMP . '/xml/' . $filename;
    $file = new File($path, false);

    if($file->exists()){
        $string = $file->read();

        $file->close();
        $file->delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, the [CakePHP File API](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/file-folder.html#file-api) suggests locking is handled by the framework. The exists() condition seems to be of no use here, have you tried replacing it by `if($string = $file->read())` ?

Comment: I have tried It, but no way to fix the problem @code-kobold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`flock()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) to obtain (or attempt to obtain) a file lock and act accordingly.

Comment: can you please make an example of how to use It inside my script please?

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri I can't since you have used some "File" class and  not classic file handles. Maybe the "File" class has a lock method already built in. The `flock()` documentation has some examples.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I have seen flock() documentation but I would like to know what is the better way to do It

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri I see no reason to not use `flock()` here since it exists for this very purpose.

Answer (score 2):

It's called a race condition, and when working with files you could lock the file when process A uses it, it locks it, then other processes would check if it's locked and if it is then do nothing. Then unlock the file when process A has finished with it.

Comment: can you please make an example of how to use It inside my script please?